# Logical Boolean Negation Operator in R: Precedence and Association

Tags: r, logical-operators

Can someone explain to me how '!' works in R?
I was confused when I first saw this:

```
> x = c(1, 1) * !c(TRUE, FALSE)
> y = c(2, 2) * c(TRUE, FALSE) 
> z = c(1, 1) * !c(TRUE, FALSE) + c(2, 2) * c(TRUE, FALSE) 
> x + y
[1] 2 1
> z
[1] 0 1
```

It's so strange and can lead to many miscalculations yet I cannot find it in the documentation.
I am using R 4.0.2

Comment: `!` is for negation. What exactly is not clear for you?

Comment: as @tmfmnk said, it is for negation, if you are confused you can always try what is going on via `print`. would this clarify it for you?
https://repl.it/repls/ComplicatedForsakenParentheses#main.r

Comment: Many operators auto-cast into the next-higher class of object, for instance, `logical` -> `integer` (`0L` and `1L`) -> `numeric` (`0` and `1`), and if going straight to strings, `character` (`"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`). Because of this, `1+TRUE` is `2`, and `0*TRUE` is `0`. `c(1,1)*!c(T,F)` --> `c(1,1)*c(F,T)` --> `c(1,1)*c(0,1)` --> `c(0,1)`, similar for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `!` operator has *lower* precedence than the addition operator `+`. The expression

```
c(1, 1) * !c(TRUE, FALSE) + c(2, 2) * c(TRUE, FALSE)
```

is parsed as

```
c(1, 1) * !( c(TRUE, FALSE) + c(2, 2) * c(TRUE, FALSE) )
```

and NOT as

```
(c(1, 1) * !c(TRUE, FALSE)) + (c(2, 2) * c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

which is probably what you (and most other people) were expecting. See `?Syntax` for a complete list of operator precedence.